# I need insight on building standalone Shiny applications to be shared with clients

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm interested to learn if there is a precedent for building standalone Shiny applications on a not-quite-production scale.  Some context: We have several clients for which we've built small Shiny tools for their internal use.  Some applications are deployed to Shinyapps.io, some have been shared locally (requiring the user to have R and other dependencies installed).  Neither of these are ideal solutions.

##### Limitations:

Having clients install applications locally is tricky for a number of reasons, things like: extra mental load on clients, issues regarding dependencies, etc.  Deployment to shinyapps.io or a Shiny server is not ideal because: 1) We, as a smaller company, lack employees to manage extra IT infrastructure. 2) shinyapps.io can be a bit rigid (some clients might like to share the application internally). 3) Some of these projects are very small and don't warrant the development time of configuring a Shiny server.

##### Possible Solutions:

###### R Portable Paired with Chrome Portable

I have successfully built and shared a standalone Shiny application using the code and instructions from [this repository](https://github.com/derryleng/Shiny_Desktop_App/tree/master).  This seems like a fair solution for windows machines, assuming you're comfortable with clients having access to your source code.  My main question is: is this solution secure?  Are there security concerns regarding sharing installations R-Portable and Chrome-Portable with clients?  The general consensus seems to be that portableapps.com is safe, at least for personal use.  But is it secure to the point of sharing it with a client?

###### Photon/Electron

I know there are a number of resources which provide tools to package Shiny applications with Electron (Photon, RInno, electricShine).  However, after looking into a number of these tools, many of them seem like they aren't actively being maintained.  Is this a concern?  Are folks using any of these tools, and if so, what has been your experience?

Any insight is appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: I just did this and spent many unproductive hours trying to get any of those electron based solutions to work with no success. I ended up doing something like the former, but using a regular installation of R and configured it to launch in the default web browser, since there almost any computer will already have a web browser on it. I can't really answer your question about security concerns with R portable.